# Does Hibernate always use eager loading when searchi by some children properties?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

Can you please help me to solve this problem.
I have 2 classes. One is Device, second is Alert generated by device.
Device class looks like.

```
public class Device
{
    private Long deviceId;  
    private String deviceName;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Alert> alerts;
}

public class Alert
{
    private Long deviceId;  
    private String alertText;
    private String alertType;
    private Date alertTime;
}
```

then I want to get all devices generated alerts. For this I use Criteria.API

```
Criteria crit= session.createCriteria(Device.class);
Criteria alertCriteria=crit.createCreateria("alerts");
alertCriteria.add(Resrictions.between("alertTime", startDate, endDate));

crit.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

Problem with this approach that generated SQL query retrieves all alerts then applying result transformer.
it looks something like this

```
select deviceID,deviceName,alertText,alertType,alertTime from devices d, alerts a left join  a.deviceID=d.deviceID;
```

This query is not efficient. In case when alerts table is huge it takes several minutes.
Therefore I have some questions:

- will adding `alertCriteria.add(Resrictions.between("alertTime"),startDate,endDate);` always result in fetching alerts in one select? How to avoid it?
- How can I get all distinct devices having alerts without using ResultTransformer?

---

After Implementing second example I am gettin NPE in hibernate code:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getProjectedTypes(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.createAndSetInnerQuery(SubqueryExpression.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.toSqlString(SubqueryExpression.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.(CriteriaLoader.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)

Answer (score 0):

answer 1: when you filter by child properties the sql has to join to the childtable to get the associated root entities

answer 2: if you need devices that have any alerts in the given range

```
List<Device> devicesWithAlerts = session.createCriteria(Device.class, "device")
    .createCriteria("alerts")
        .add(Resrictions.between("alertTime", startDate, endDate))
    .setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
    .List<Device>();

// or more efficiently because only wanted entities are loaded

List<Device> devicesWithAlerts = session.createCriteria(Device.class, "device")
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("id", DetachedCriteria.For(Device.class)
        .CreateCriteria("alerts")
            .add(Resrictions.between("alertTime", startDate, endDate))
        .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Id()))
        ))
    .List<Device>();
```